# Is it a good design to use a spring's MVC tag ( let's say form:input tag) within a custom myCustomTag.tag file implementation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a myCustomTag.tag file to implement my custom tag in spring MVC supported project. I know that the developer using the myCustomTag would use the myCustomTag within the spring provided  tag. For E.g. :

```
<form:form action="..." commandName="...>
     <myprefix:mycustomTag ............  />
   </form:form>
```

Is it a good design to use a spring's MVC tag ( let's say form:input tag) within a custom myCustomTag.tag file implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, I don't see a reason why you would not want to use spring tags within a custom tag.

For example, for a large form, you might want to separate sections into their own tags and spring tags are perfectly ok to be used there (ie, if it is syntactically allowed).